# how to set environment variable in azure function python

Tags: java, python-3.x, azure-functions

I am trying to install jdk in python azure function with

*pip install install-jdk*

import jdk

path_to_java_home = jdk.install('15', jre=true)

now I am trying to set the path for JAVA_HOME

how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Setting a environment variable in an azure function is done by:

1. Navigating to your azure function in the azure portal
2. Under settings go to "configuration"
3. Click the "+ new application setting" to add the variable
4. Enter the name and value and then save
5. The variable can now be used as an environment variable in the code